# Can I use Amazon's SES to send a display name with the source email address?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've got some .Net code I'm switching from the System.Net.MailMessage to Amazon SES and their .Net SDK v2. Is it possible to include a display name with SES using the SDK similar to the MailMessage object?

The relevant part of the old code looks something like this:

```
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(_user.Email, _user.DisplayName);
    message.To.Add(toAddress);
```

The relevant part of the new code (so far):

```
        SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest()
        {
            Source = _user.Email
        };
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the Java SDK you can include the display name in the `sender` field using the format:

`John Doe <john.doe@example.com>`

I assume it is the same with the .NET SDK.

Comment: Works with .NET SDK too, unfortunately if it not documented it is not so reliable.

Comment: I think, it's RFC-based so okay

Answer (score 3):

Just use the .ToString() method from the MailAddress object, and you'll get the `John Doe <john.doe@example.com>` string. Send this string to AWS.

Comment: This also works for non-ASCII characters. Single liner example:  `static readonly string senderAddress = new MailAddress("no-reply@email.com", "=?UTF-8?B?" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Моя компания")) + "?=").ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

You can set this in your App Settings or WebConfig and concatenate the name and email in your method like this:

```
var toAddress = $"{_configuration["AWS-SES:SenderName"]} <{_configuration["AWS-SES:SenderAddress"]}>";
```

its found for .NET